# @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) in spring?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, propagation

If I have the following code :

```
@Component
public class A{ 

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void a(){
    //logic
    b();
 //logic
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void b(){
    //logic
} 
}
```

How many transactions open Spring in this code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter. When calling `b()` from `a()` it won't be going through the proxy, so any transactional attributes on `b()` won't be considered.

The example code has 1 transaction open if `a()` or `b()` is called through the proxy (i.e. outside of the class) and there isn't a transaction in progress already.

Answer (score 3):

I add to @pablo answer the notice that in your example you cannot see the actual difference because your call your method within the same object which make @transaction behavior  on the second method transparent with no effect :

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional

Answer (score 2):

From spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html

> REQUIRED:
>   Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists

It only creates one transaction.

Comment: additionally even if a new transaction was created it wouldn't work because it wouldn't be able to Proxy it.

Comment: what about Requires_New?

Comment: Will create a new one even if a transaction exists.

Answer (score 1):

Refering to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) `Propagation.REQUIRED`support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists. The answer to your question is :

1 transaction, if there is no transaction when A#a() is called.

0- zero if there is already one because it will be reused.