# Spring propagation required from spring docs

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

Adding to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984379/transactionalpropagation-propagation-required-in-spring), what if method b() is called from a() via proxy ? Will it be a separate logical transaction with same propagation and isolation settings as mentioned in the docs:

> When the propagation setting is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, a logical
>   transaction scope is created for each method upon which the setting is
>   applied. Each such logical transaction scope can determine
>   rollback-only status individually, with an outer transaction scope
>   being logically independent from the inner transaction scope. Of
>   course, in case of standard PROPAGATION_REQUIRED behavior, all these
>   scopes will be mapped to the same physical transaction. So a
>   rollback-only marker set in the inner transaction scope does affect
>   the outer transaction’s chance to actually commit (as you would expect
>   it to).

Can anyone explain the difference between:

> a logical transaction scope is created for each method upon which the
>   setting is applied. Each such logical transaction scope can determine
>   rollback-only status individually, with an outer transaction scope
>   being logically independent from the inner transaction scope.

and

> Of course, in case of standard PROPAGATION_REQUIRED behavior, all
>   these scopes will be mapped to the same physical transaction.

Comment: Not sure why you think there should be a difference. the second sentence completes the first one. What exactly is your question.

Comment: In #1, if i call met2() from met1() using proxy with both methods having same propagation(REQUIRED) and but rollback for only met2(), i have observed met1() is also rolled back. So, the statement, outer transaction and inner transaction have independent rollbacks was not understandable. is #1 sentence generic for all propagation types ?

Comment: Each transctional method defines a tranaction scope. If the propagation is required, then the physical transaction associated to the met2 scope is the same as the physical transaction associated to the met1 scope. So setting rollback status from met2 rollbacks the physical transaction started when calling met1.